# java mapping table row to object (automatically)

Tags: java

I'd like to get a row from table [String name, String password, int something] 
and map it into an object User which has 3 attributes like above with getters and setters
are there any ways to do it automatically? 
I thought about reflection but couldnt get it to work yet and also heard it is slow.

Comment: Ever thought of using `JPA/Hibernate`?

Comment: i am using jpa/eclipselink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PropertyUtlils.setProperty](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#setProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29), if you are finding Java Reflection bit confusing.

`PropertyUtils` is part of **commons-beanutils.jar**

Answer (score 0):

`Hibernate` is one you can use. With it you can map your database tables to java object using few xml configurations